# NUGET package restore error NU1106 relating to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have an ASP.Net Core web app "Corp.App" thats has begun failing to build with NuGet error NU1106.

Corp.App has (among others)

- A package reference to **Corp.Package**
- A project reference to **Corp.Project**

both the package and project have package references to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />`), Corp.App does not.

As all the version numbers are as expected I'm unsure how to resolve these conflicts.

```
 
Failed to restore C:\Repos\x\Corp.App.csproj (in 894 ms).

NuGet package restore failed. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.

1>C:\Repos\x\Corp.App.csproj : error NU1106: Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions': 
    Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 8.0.0) (via package/Corp.Package 1.1.4), 
    Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 8.0.0) (via project/Corp.Project 1.0.0), 
    Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 8.0.0) (via package/Corp.Project 1.0.0),
    Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 6.0.0) Framework: (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
    
1>C:\Repos\x\Corp.App.csproj : error NU1106: Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions': 
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 8.0.0) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 8.0.0), 
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 8.0.0) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 8.0.0),
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 6.0.0), 
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 8.0.0) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 8.0.0), 
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 7.0.0) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 7.0.0) Framework: (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
    
1>C:\Repos\x\Corp.App.csproj : error NU1106: Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions': 
    Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 8.0.0) (via package/Corp.Package 1.1.4), 
    Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 8.0.0) (via project/Corp.Project 1.0.0), 
    Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 8.0.0) (via package/Corp.Project 1.0.0), 
    Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 6.0.0) Framework: (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0 RuntimeIdentifier: win10-x64)

1>C:\Repos\x\Corp.App.csproj : error NU1106: Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions': 
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 8.0.0) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 8.0.0),
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 8.0.0) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 8.0.0), 
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 6.0.0), 
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 8.0.0) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 8.0.0), 
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 7.0.0) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 7.0.0) Framework: (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0 RuntimeIdentifier: win10-x64)

1>Done building project "Corp.App.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: Update `Corp.App` (to .NET 8) and packages referenced in it.

Comment: Based on the output `Core.App`   has dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` of older versions which seems to result in the issue. I was not able to repro, you can try to close/reopen IDE and cleaning bin/obj folders first. If this does not help - try updating corresponding `Microsoft.Extensions.*` packages. If this does not help - please provide a [mre].

Comment: Is your problem solved ? Have you check [Install and manage packages in Visual Studio using the NuGet Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Open NuGet Package Manager for the **solution** (not for the project), and from the Update Tab update everything you find, it should solve the problem